# Schengen Visa or National Dependent visa for Poland

Tags: dependent-visa, poland

I have recently got my type A - work permit to work for an investment bank in Wroclaw. My national work visa appointment with the Polish consulate is on 11th March, 2019.

My spouse has done her Masters in Business Administration and is currently working in India. However, she would like to join me in Wroclaw during vacations or sabbatical leaves and also intends to apply for a job in Wroclaw. Is it wise, that she applies for a National dependent visa? Or should she rather apply for a Schengen visa, as she is currently working in India. Can the visa officer question her, since she will not stay at a stretch for one year?

Comment: It would be very helpful, if someone who has knowledge of immigration matters here can share their tips and experience. I'd really appreciate it! Cheers.

Comment: Has your wife identified a specific job she wants to apply for?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that it boils down to how likely it seems that your wife would actually want to move to Poland (that is, how likely she is to find a job, or to decide to move to Poland without finding a job there).  It might also depend on whether employers will talk to her before she has authorization to work in Poland (that is, they might not be satisfied with "I am eligible to apply for a dependent visa that will allow me to work").

You also have to weigh the relative costs, of course, which only you can do.

In principle, a plan to apply for the dependent visa up front without necessarily moving to Poland right away should not doom the application.  But I have no personal experience with Polish immigration officials, so anyone reading this who has experience please post a comment.

Comment: A follow-up to this. My spouse has resigned from her job in India, so that she can join me in Poland and stay with me. Does it indicate clear motive to Consular officer?

Comment: @Quasar I suppose it would, yes.